# Java Generics. Child extends Parent

Tags: java, generics, vaadin, java-5

Can you please help me with a generics. 
I have a requirement where I have a UI form but based on type, form changes completely. I have created Parent DTO with common fields and child DTOs for each type of form. Using vaadin for validation. How do I get this working. bind method on childdto giving error.

> The type ChildlDTO does not define getTitle(capture#10-of ? extends
>   ParentDTO) that is applicable here
>
> The method writeBean(capture#10-of ? extends ParentDTO) in the type
>   Binder is not applicable for the
>   arguments (ParentDTO)

```
private ParentDTO dto= new ChildDTO();
private Binder<? extends ParentDTO> binder = new Binder<>(ParentDTO.class);

    binder.forField(type).asRequired("Please select type")
        .bind(ParentDTO::getType, ParentDTO::setType);
```

compile errors below for bind and write methods

```
    binder.forField(title).asRequired("Please select Title")
    .bind(ChildDTO::getTitle, ChildDTO::setTitle);

    binder.writeBean(control);
```

Parent and child classes

```
public abstract class ParentDTO
public class ChildDTO extends ParentDTO {
```

Vaadin Binder

```
public class Binder<BEAN> implements Serializable {
```

bind and write methods

```
Binding<BEAN, TARGET> bind(ValueProvider<BEAN, TARGET> getter,
        Setter<BEAN, TARGET> setter);
public void writeBean(BEAN bean) throws ValidationException {
```

Also

Comment: This: `Binder<? extends ParentDTO> binder` needs to be `Binder<ChildDTO> = new Binder<>(ChildDTO.class)`.

Comment: getTitle is only in one of the child objects and not in parentdto.
I can't create Binder definition as Binder<ChildDTO> as I could have also have other child objects  Binder<AnotherChildDTO>

Comment: I could potentially get rid of 
    binder.forField(type).asRequired("Please select type")
        .bind(ParentDTO::getType, ParentDTO::setType);
By using childDTO instead as child have access to parent not other way

Comment: Why do you tag your question with java-5 when you are clearly using java 8 constructs?

Comment: Generics came in Java 5

Answer (score 1):

Just go with a `Binder<ParentDTO>`, then you can also write extending classes to it.

However, you are not going to be able to do this

```
binder.forField(title).asRequired("Please select Title")
    .bind(ChildDTO::getTitle, ChildDTO::setTitle);
```

As there's no guarantee that what is passed to it is a `ChildDTO`.

If you need that method, then you could do something like this, and create one function for each type of DTO:

```
public Binder<ChildDTO> createChildBinder(ChildDTO bean) {
    Binder<ChildDTO> binder = createBinder(bean);
    TextField titleField = new TextField();
    add(titleField);
    binder.forField(titleField).asRequired()
            .bind(ChildDTO::getTitle, ChildDTO::setTitle);
    binder.readBean(bean);
    return binder;
}

public Binder<ChildTwoDTO> createChildBinder(ChildTwoDTO bean) {
    Binder<ChildTwoDTO> binder = createBinder(bean);
    TextField languageField = new TextField();
    add(languageField);
    binder.forField(languageField).asRequired()
            .bind(ChildTwoDTO::getLanguage, ChildTwoDTO::setLanguage);
    binder.readBean(bean);
    return binder;
}

public <T extends ParentDTO> Binder<T> createBinder(T bean) {
    Binder<T> binder = new Binder<>();
    binder.forField(typeField).asRequired("Better fill this...")
            .bind(ParentDTO::getType, ParentDTO::setType);
    return binder;
}
```

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/cDhZTSKt)